# How can append into a list during Cython parallelization?

Tags: parallel-processing, cython

I have to share a variable into Cython parallel context.

I want to do something like this:

```py
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel
cdef list factorize(cdef int n, cdef int limit):
    cdef list factors
    cdef int p

    factors = []
    with cython.nogil, parallel():
        for p in prange(3, limit, 2):
            if p * p > n: break
            if n % p == 0: 
                factors.append(p)
                n = n // p
    if n > 1: factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

How can I append into the `factors` list variable during the parallel context? Moreover, how why cannot I do the operation `n // p` without gil?
Can I implement this method in this way?

PS: This is only an example but I have the same for-loop in other context so I want to know if I can parallelize this type of for-loop and, if it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: A list is ordered.  If several processes can append to the same list 'at-once' who or what controls the order in the list?  Do you care?

Comment: @hpaulj the order, in this case, for me, is not important. I have not reflected at all that this could be a problem because of the order does not matter in this context. So, may it works with a set?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *why cannot I do the operation `n // p` without `GIL`?*

The GIL-lock is for a reason used as the means, that re-`[SERIAL]`-ises any concurrent code-execution, and this principally prevents ( avoids right by the locking ) any two threads from race and collide in their attempts to modify a common object ( the **`n`**-being the first such candidate, and the **`factors[]`** being for the same reason the second one )

Without locking the
**`G`** lobal .............. <sub>meaning no one but I own ( or not ) the globally respected GIL</sub>
 **`I`** nterpereter .... <sub>yes, we still live inside the interpreted code ecosystem</sub>
**`L`** ock ................ <sub>must wait, till ACK'd my GIL-ownership, no way to proceed to modify objects without 1st having it</sub>
all,
 concurrently executed **`prange(3, limit, 2)`**-many code-execution-paths, would headbang into an attempt to assign into **`int n`** (sure, re-associate, if python pedantic) and the same trouble gets experienced a row before, on an attempt to re-organise a list **`factors[]`**, as the **`.append()`**-method needs to do some internal surgery inside a "live"-patient.

If it were not GIL-lock-anesthesised, so as not to move for a moment, when the GIL-owner and only the GIL-owner can take tools and cut and re-organise the patient's internal state and release the lock only after the surgery is complete, to let the `factors[]` live further, after the GIL-lock is released as the surgery was safely finished,
no one would guestimate the tortures that would happen to the internal state if many surgeons cut internal venes and whatever else inside such a unhappy patient.

The GIL-locking simply prevents this disastrous massacre from ever happening, but, at a cost of re-`[SERIAL]`-ising all surgery operations...

> **Q** : *How can I append into the factors list variable during the parallel context?*

The best way it is to append into privately modified / exclusively used-for-writing objects and then "*`sum_reduce`*" 'em after the ( now principally independently appending ) parallel-sections finish their work.

Comment: With `sum_reduce` do you mean the `map-reduce` paradigm? Have Cython it?

Comment: @G.F OpenMP (and probably other parallel libraries) have what are known as "reduction variables". If you're doing a sum inside a loop each thread keeps its own count, and then at the end of the loop the results from all the threads are added together. I think user3666197 is suggesting you use a similar approach for your list. It isn't quite as straightforward though - you'll have to implement it manually.

Comment: @G.F With the *`sum_reduce`* I do mean the *`sum_reduce`* - a process of **reduction** of all the finished "parallel" code-execution paths ( well, pedantically "just"-concurrent ), using the **summation** as the reduction-operator. This is a principal way, how to re-collect partial results from many working streams. As an example, if the reduction-operator were **multiplication** over integers produced by the `prange()`-ed workers instead, you may finally gain a smart computation of a `factorial()` etc. Feel free to try it in python IDE,you will get the point right when you test it. It is easy